# scrape multiple pages website with python and beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from quikbook.com. I can scrape the first page of hotel names but I don't know how to navigate to the second page. This is the tag of the next page button:

```
<a id="nextLink" href="javascript:void(0)" cachekey="62707097:1515f4a1462:2e0c" cachelocation="10.186.170.117:7300" class="btn b-tertiary"><span>Next Page</span></a>
```

My questions:
1) how to get the script associated with its javascript:void(0)
2) how to navigate to the second page. 
I have tried to find the page number using Chrome inspection tool, but there is no page number. 
Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this it would be best to use a web driver tool like selenium.  If you only want to do it with beautiful soup, you can hack it through URL modification.

If you look at the URL for the pages, you will notice that the next page has the `cachelocation` and `chachekey` in it. Here is an example URL:

http://www.quikbook.com/availabilitySearchNewYorkA?marketId=0&arrivalDate=12%2F02%2F2015&nbNights=1&nbRooms=1&nbAdults=1&radius=0&lat=0.0&lon=0.0&nbChildren=0&location=New+York&sort=OVERALL_VALUE&hotelId=0&minPrice=0&maxPrice=500&starRatingMin=1.0&includeCashbackHotel=true&starRatingMax=5.0&cacheLocation=10.178.144.41%3A7300&cacheKey=698fae78%3A151602773ee%3A-301&showMapTab=&propertyName=&destinationId=

The Next button on that page is:

```
<a id="nextLink" href="javascript:void(0)" cachekey="-1df6c48d:1516012d60d:6b74" cachelocation="10.186.170.66:7300" class="btn b-tertiary"><span>Next Page</span></a>
```

Replace these in the above url:

`&cacheLocation=10.186.170.66%3A7300`
`&cacheKey=-1df6c48d%3A1516012d60d%3A6b74`

And you get the URL for the next page

http://www.quikbook.com/availabilitySearchNewYorkA?marketId=0&arrivalDate=12%2F02%2F2015&nbNights=1&nbRooms=1&nbAdults=1&radius=0&lat=0.0&lon=0.0&nbChildren=0&location=New+York&sort=OVERALL_VALUE&hotelId=0&minPrice=0&maxPrice=500&starRatingMin=1.0&includeCashbackHotel=true&starRatingMax=5.0&cacheLocation=10.186.170.66%3A7300&cacheKey=-1df6c48d%3A1516012d60d%3A6b74&showMapTab=&propertyName=&destinationId=

Note that `:` was replaced by `%3A` so the URL could handle it.

Comment: thanks alot, but my problem is to get those cachekey and cachelocation when doing automation. As you suggested, I am trying selenium and it seems much easier.